# FileSystemException (FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'file.txt' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2))

Tags: flutter, dart

```
readLrTime() async {
  Directory fileDic = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  String filePath = fileDic.path;
  File file = File("$filePath/file.txt");
  var lines = await file.readAsLines();
  var mylrTime = lines[0];
  return mylrTime;
}
```

this is my code and I've faced this error

> FileSystemException (FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'file.txt' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2))

Comment: what is your running os? android? ios?

Comment: My running os is android

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have added read and write permissions on the android manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application...
```

Comment: I've added but it continues to give same error

Comment: and what about this package to handle permissions
https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler